# game is not proper display using xcode 6 GM seed on ipad

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I am trying to build and test my game on iPad mini iOS 8 using Xcode 6 GM seed all i am seeing is this half way screen. I don't know why Xcode 6 is not showing the full screen. However same code if play on Xcode 5.1.1 then it works fine on ipad and play game at X2 on iPad. I am maing iphone game but i a testing that on ipad too as ipad also can play the game.Can any body solve my issue i want to submit my app using new sdk. I found one more thing on xcode 5.1.1 it's showing surface size:640*960 and on xcode 6 it's showing 960*640 which can cause problem so kindly help me to find the solution thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: yes i solve it it was due xcode issue if you make app on xcode 6 and you chose build only for ios then also change ipad landscape to portrait from xcode setting.